# How to avoid moving child object when parent is moved?

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to avoid moving inline child objects of parent when parent record is moved?

My use case:

There is TYPO3 record (parent) of type X which has inline relation to record of type Y (child).

Following configuration is loaded:

```
TCAdefaults.Y {
   pid = 129
}
```

1. I am adding new X record on page 1 and inline relation of type Y. X
   is created with pid = 1 and Y is created with pid = 129. So far
   good.
2. Now I am moving record X to page 2. Both X and Y have pid 2 now. How can 
   I avoid that? I don't want inline record Y to change pid when X is moved in backend (example cut and paste functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a TCA configuration for this purpose. Add this to your TCA inline field configuration:

```
'behavior' => [
  'disableMovingChildrenWithParent' => true
],
```

The docs: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Inline.html#disablemovingchildrenwithparent